# .NET MVC issue with multiple routes

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have registered a route in my .NET MVC 5 application like this :

```
 routes.MapRoute(
   "Books", // Route name
   "Books/{id}", // URL with parameters*
   new { controller = "Books", action = "Index", id = 
   UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
```

Now the web controller and action index is accessible through:

```
mylocalhost:8080/Books/50ShadesOfGrey
```

What the problem now is I have another method where I post the data with this parameter like this:

```
  @if (Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"] != null)
   {
       @:DoScan('@Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]');
   }
```

DoScan is a javascript method which accepts the book name as parameter, which should then post the book name to this method I have in same controller (Books), which is defined like this:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult LoadData(string bookName)
  {
   // method sould now be called but nothing happens??
  }
```

I tested it without the route that I recently added and the post works just fine... But when I add this route it's like this LoadData HttpPost method gets ignored completely?? I feel like I should add another route in route config just for it, but I'm not really sure what to do here? Can someone help me out ?

P.S.

The route defined in the post method is like this:

```
/Books/LoadData/
```

But the action never gets triggered?

P.S. The method gets called through datatables ajax call like this:

```
 "ajax": {
           "url": "/Books/LoadData/",
           "type": "POST",
            "data": {
            "bookName": _bookName /*Parameter I passed through calling the function*/
           },
```

Comment: Can you post the code that does the post in js, DoScan that is?

Comment: @Andrei I have included the code with explanation

Comment: @Andrei I should mention that without this newly added route everything works just fine... When the route is added that's when the method never gets called... There's something wrong with the route I added or I need to add another route for this method .. ?

Comment: Your first URL example is this : `mylocalhost:8080/Books/50ShadesOfGrey` So if you want a different URL which includes `LoadData` for your post method, you will need to register another URL. Your very first method looks like a GET so you could use the same URL for both and look at using the `[FromBody]` tag and not passing the data through the URL. Just noticed your procedure was called LoadData... @Andrei 's answer is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet you also have a default route in your config. So in actuality you have:

```
Books/{id}
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

MVC will pick the first that matches your request. Request in the post method is "Books/LoadData" with some data. What data exactly is there is not important, what is important is that it is not the part of the URL.

So "Books/LoadData" matches the first route, with "LoadData" being {id}. Thus your request goes to Index action, and LoadData action is not triggered.

Your intention was obviously to have this request captured with the default route, but again, MVC picks first that matches.

To fix this you need to either remove your route, or add a third one *above* it:

```
Books/LoadData
Books/{id}
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

Note that this new route does not have URL parameters, nor does it need any - data is being passed in the request body instead.

Comment: Something like this ?   routes.MapRoute(
            "LoadData", // Route name
            "Books/LoadData", // URL with parameters*
            new { controller = "Books", action = "LoadData" }
            );